# Data Generation for MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

does anyone know any tool for 'code generation' using MVC2?

I know that ASP .NET has 'Dynamic Site' template (I know that don't generate any code), but I searching for one that generates code using MVC2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, I found some T4 that are partially answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).

Comment: Not rely. I know how to use templates, but my idea was as 'dynamic data', generate backoffice code, but instead of ASP. NET using MVC

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on your question, then. DD doesn't give you much besides routing and templates.